# R: CoxPH model with a categorical variable that has too many levels

Tags: categorical-data, survival, cox-model, many-categories

I have dataset df consist of 8000 observations

```
org_id property1 property2  property3 uptimeDay event
```

and org_id is a categorical variable with 1199 different levels. The other two variables or properties of an organization and are numerical.

```
coxp_1<-coxph(formula = Surv(uptimeDay, event,type='right') ~ (peroperty1 + property3)^2 + property2 +  I(as.factor(org_id)), data = df_cox)
```

I am planning to run the following cox model in R but I keep getting this error msg which I am guessing is caused due to the fact that my categorical variable (org_id) has to many different levels.

```
Error in fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
```

Does anybody know what could be a potential solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't think that `traceback()` should be used as a predictor in your call to `coxph`.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you want 1198 different coefficients for org_id. Why not treat it as a random effect and use coxme from the coxme package?

Comment: @mdwey because my goal is to understand the difference in the response variable for each of these organizations. Is that possible with random effect?

Comment: The usual rule of thumb to avoid overfitting is that you need about 15 events per effective predictor variable, where a categorical variable counts effectively as 1 less than the number of its levels. So even if you solved the problem with the error message you can't really accomplish what you want with a 1199-level categorical variable and only 8000 observations.

Comment: Just checking to see if `peroperty1` is spelled correctly in your code.  Always check the trivial!

Comment: Look at  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/227125/preprocess-categorical-variables-with-many-values/277302#277302  and links therein. Maybe some similar ideas can be used with cox models?

Answer (score 1):

The Cox Proportional Hazards' Model needs your event variable to have at least one event and one non-event (event = 0) for each level of the categorical variable. Otherwise, it's called Perfect Classification. To check this see the results of:
xtabs(~event + org_id, data = df_cox)

My guess is since your dataset has 8000 observations and 1199 different level, a solution would be to increase the number of observations or club different levels together.